# recording 2 videos of 2 different pictures

Tags: python, pi-2, raspicam, opencv

I'm using raspberry pi with python 
and I'm trying to record a video of :

1. regular video stream
2. a picture from that stream that showes a circle identification (using hough transform )

> cv2.circle = (cimg , (i[0],i[1],i[2] , (0,255,0) ,1 )

is this possible ? 
and if it is , how ? :)